# Arduino project using infrared sensor and usb communication

Tags: usb, communication, arduino

I am planning on doing a small arduino project and would like to know if what I'm thinking would work with a regular arduino board. I'm thinking of buying an Arduino Uno for my project, along with an IR LED and an IR sensor. So here's what I want to go with this:

I want to point the LED towards the sensor, so that the sensor is always detecting light. Then', I'll start "cutting" that light (say, with with my hand) several times. I want the arduino program to time the intervals between the times the light is "cut" and send these times to my computer via USB, so I can process this data.

I've seen many people talk about serial communication between an arduino board and a computer, but I'm not sure how that works. Will it use the same usb connector I use to upload programs to the board, or do I have to buy anything else?

EDIT: tl;dr: I guess my question, in the end, is twofold:
1) Am I able to "talk" to my computer using the built-in USB connector on the board, or is that used solely for uploading programs and I need to buy another one? and
2) Is this project feasible with an Arduino Uno board?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your project is very feasible.

1. You use the built in USB connector to both program the device and communicate with it. Check out some examples on the [Serial Reference Page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial)
2. For reading the sensor, you'll want to use either a [digital](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalRead) or [analog](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead) input. For a digital input, you'll likely have to external components to control the light threshold, but it will provide a simple yes or no if something is in front of it. With an analog input, you can use a threshold in code to determine when your hand passes.
3. Timing can either be done on device with the [Millis()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis1.1.2.) function or on the connected computer.

Comment: Just an update on this: I have started this project and it's working perfectly! I currently check if the state on the pin has changed on every loop() call, and act accordingly. Looking to switch to interrupts next, just to see how it works. Thanks a lot for your answer!